# Problema con RecyclerView

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo un RecyclerView y cuando ejecuto la aplicacion no me muestra nada u.u

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardViewHist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        cardview:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        cardview:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        cardview:cardElevation="4dp"
        cardview:cardMaxElevation="5dp"
        cardview:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        cardview:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        cardview:contentPadding="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1 ">

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/etfechaRealizadaH"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/claveTareaH"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

            <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1 ">

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/etFechaProgramadaH"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/etComentariosH"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>


            <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="0,1 ">

                <TableRow>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/etFechaAltaH"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/etUsuarioAltaH"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

`fragment` Histórico:

```
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Contacto"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_margin="15dip"
        android:text="CONTACTO"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Vehiculo"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dip"
        android:text="VEHICULO"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Historico"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_margin="15dip"
        android:text="HISOTRICO"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>

</GridLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_historicos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

clase `Adapter`:

```
public class HistoricoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HistoricoAdapter.HistoricoViewHolder> {

   private ArrayList<TareaObj> historicoTareas;
   private FragmentActivity activity;

    public HistoricoAdapter(ArrayList<TareaObj> historicoTareas, FragmentActivity activity) {
    this.historicoTareas = historicoTareas;
    this.activity = activity;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HistoricoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_cardview_historico, viewGroup);
        return new HistoricoViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HistoricoViewHolder historicoViewHolder, int i) {

        final TareaObj historico = historicoTareas.get(i);
        historicoViewHolder.fechaRealizada.setText(historico.getFechaRealizada());
        historicoViewHolder.fechaProgramada.setText(historico.getTareaFechaProg());
        historicoViewHolder.fechaAlta.setText(historico.getFechaRegistrada());
        historicoViewHolder.clave.setText(historico.getTareaTipoClave());
        historicoViewHolder.comentarios.setText(historico.getComentarios());
        historicoViewHolder.usuarioAlta.setText(historico.getUsuarioAlta());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    public class HistoricoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView fechaRealizada, fechaProgramada, fechaAlta, clave, comentarios, usuarioAlta;

        CardView tarjeta;

        public HistoricoViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            tarjeta = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardViewHist);
            fechaRealizada = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etfechaRealizadaH);
            fechaProgramada = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etFechaProgramadaH);
            fechaAlta = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etFechaAltaH);
            clave = itemView.findViewById(R.id.claveTareaH);
            comentarios = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etComentariosH);
            usuarioAlta = itemView.findViewById(R.id.etUsuarioAltaH);
        }
    }
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme u.u 
Ya estuve depurando y si pasa los valores que debe, pero no sé porque no se muestre nada en la vista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la función `getItemCount` estas retornando 0, debes retornar la cantidad de elementos del recycler view

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return historicoTareas.size();
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! No lo había notado u.u